# No response by sending a rest request and getting back status 200 ok

Tags: jquery, rest, firebug, getjson

I send a rest request to a server and getting back a status 200 ok, but there is no content in the response.

```
$.getJSON("http://192.168.0.94:8084/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/sfasda/", function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

I debugged with firebug this and are the headers:

```
Connection  close
Content-Length  21
Content-Type    text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Pragma  dssession=188802.418847.903604,dssessionexpires=1200000
Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    192.168.0.94:8084
Origin  http://192.168.0.92
Referer http://192.168.0.92/visuals/index.php?page=pincodescreen
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
```

what do i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doing a cross domain request, which won't work due to JavaScript [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Your request originates from a document of `http://192.168.0.92`, while the target is `http://192.168.0.94:8084/`. To my knowledge even different ports trigger the policy making it inpossible to request data directly.

Assuming you have control over the second server, rewrite your request to use JSONP.

Comment: too bad, i have no control over the second server

Comment: it is possible to do this by using my browser or php but i want client side execution

Comment: you could put an proxy script on your server. your client would then call this script, which in turn would fetch the resource from the remote server and forward it to your client. the client can then work with the data in any way necessary. for your client there would be only one server to talk to and thus you would have no problemes with the same origin policy.